# Interprocess communication between iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, ipc, communication

I need to implement a communication between a central app that runs always and other apps that may request services from that app. There should also be a way to communicate back to those requests even if they have been closed (i.e. loading them to get the responds). What is the best way to implement that on iPhone? (on Android a solution could be done using StartActivity)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On the same device? Impossible with official APIs.

Comment: What is the best way to implement IPC if both apps are running? (same device)

Comment: Go through a web service. And investigate the limited definition of "running in the background" on iOS. Apps won't be able to automatically come to the foreground, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

If jailbreaking is an option, try the CPDistributedMessagingCenter class. It has a very good documentation on the iPhone Dev Wiki (just google it). You may also want to look at how I used it one of my tweaks: see the daemon's implementation [on GitHub](https://github.com/H2CO3/PwnTube/blob/68c2786de5b0c0581ab2c89e6461d2c8e50b318b/PTDaemonDelegate.m).

Comment: Useful answer, just a note for others who don't see `CPDistributedMessagingCenter` in PwnTube: you have to look at a previous version, like this one: https://github.com/H2CO3/PwnTube/tree/68c2786de5b0c0581ab2c89e6461d2c8e50b318b (I'm assuming the long identifier is a permanent marker.)